# Field Validation Rule for Location

Tags: validation

How to Lock Location Field on a Custom Object Country. The requirements are to be able to create NEW LOCATION field or Populate the Location if it's NULL upon creation the FORM. But wouldn't be able to Modify the Location field after it's ADDED or Populated in the Field.

Comment: Is this still an outstanding question?

Answer (score 2):

Simple validation rule:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Location__c))),
    ISCHANGED(Location__c)
)
```

Part 2 - Throw an error if the `Location__c` changes, but you also need to...
Part 1 - Allow the `Location__c` to change if it used to be blank